# How do I break my word and get it to let me input individual characters

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, foreach, char

I am making a Guess The Word game (it's basically hangman without the hangman) So far I can get it to pick a random word from the array and have the program place ____ in place of the word. What I need is to break up the word so the player can guess by individual letters instead of the whole word at once. I've tried changing string guess in to char guess in my while loop but if I do then I cannot us != because secretword[answer] is a string

```
string[] secretWord = new string[5];
        secretWord[0] = "Pong";
        secretWord[1] = "Crash";
        secretWord[2] = "Joust";
        secretWord[3] = "1942";
        secretWord[4] = "Tron";
        string guess = "";
        
       
        Random random = new Random();
        int answer = random.Next(secretWord.Length);
        char[] brokenword = secretWord[answer].ToCharArray();

        while(guess != secretWord[answer])
        {

            foreach(char c in brokenword)
            {
                Console.Write("_ ");
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("Enter guess: ");
            guess = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Try [Console.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-6.0) to get one char.  Or just check the string length after ReadLine.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string[] secretWord = new string[5];
        secretWord[0] = "Pong";
        secretWord[1] = "Crash";
        secretWord[2] = "Joust";
        secretWord[3] = "1942";
        secretWord[4] = "Tron";


        Random random = new Random();
        int answerNumber = random.Next(secretWord.Length);
        string brokenWord = secretWord[answerNumber];

        string resultString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < brokenWord.Length; i++)
            resultString += "_";

        while (brokenWord != resultString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(resultString);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter guess: ");

            string guess = Console.ReadLine();

            if (brokenWord.Contains(guess))
            {
                int i = brokenWord.IndexOf(guess);
                resultString = resultString.Insert(i, guess);
                resultString = resultString.Remove(i + 1, 1);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(resultString);
        Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

If I understood correctly, something similar is needed.Contains() - allows you to check if there is a string/char in the string, if there is, we add a character to the string and delete "_"